# C# faster way to compare pixels between two images and only write out the differences

Tags: c#, image

Just doing a pixel-by-pixel comparison of two images that are very similar (one is an edited version of another) and writing out the differences to a new file.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        pix1 = src.GetPixel(x, y);
        pix2 = comp.GetPixel(x, y);
        if (pix1 != pix2)
        {
            dest.SetPixel(x, y, pix1);
        }
    }
}
```

`src` and `comp` are the two images to compare and `dest` is just a new image.
It takes a fairly long time.

What's a faster way to do this?
Maybe it's not necessary to actually get the pixel in order to compare it?

Comment: thanks, your question helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare the pixels you need to read them. However, `GetPixel()` is a very slow method of doing this and not recommended unless you are just checking a very small amount of data.

To get better performance the best way is to go with unsafe-code and use pointers instead. There are lots of samples of this on the internet, below is one that I found that explains the problems a bit and offers two different solutions to this.

http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i

Be sure to check part two as well where he has some benchmarks and links to the complete source.

Comment: I have found that this pointer method is fast enough to keep up with 30fps video and this was many years ago on old hardware.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. The benchmarks look promising at least, and my usage is pretty light-weight.

Answer (score 3):

This code is similar to what I use.
Absolutely, in this case, unsafe code is the only way to go.
Marshalling a bitmap full of pixels around memory isn't necessary, and you'd have to do that twice for the comparison!

However, comparing pixels should be seen as comparing two numbers.
As a pixel is 3 bytes for each of the Red, Green and Blue components of the colour, and of course the Alpha - which is often ignored - you might want to compare values instead as UInt32's.  This would have the benefit of comparing one number (one pixel) with another, and if they're the same, then you move on.

For this to work, you don't want a byte* but a UInt32*.
Secondly, the code above doesn't consider Stride that I can see, which is where each horizontal line  of an image may actually use a different number of bytes than the sum of the pixels themselves.  As you're likely dealing with 24bits (rgb) and an alpha (a) that means the pixels should already line up, and hence, the above code should work.  Yet there's no guarantee it would 100% of the time.

It might sound like I'm being really picky, but I'm guessing performance means something to you - and coming from a gaming background, it does to me too.

(taken from above link to part 1, thanks to Karl-Johan Sjögren)

```
BitmapData bData = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, _image.Width, _image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, b.PixelFormat);
```

When you hit this line, you really need to be careful - the PixelFormat you're locking with should match one of your source image's PixelFormat.  Otherwise things might not behave quite as you expect.

from the LockBits, you get the BitmapData, which you need to dig into.

```
byte* scan0 = (byte*)bData.Scan0.ToPointer();
```

this is the line I'm referring to - I'd make this a UInt32* so you're not reading one byte per instruction, but 4 in one go, as a UInt32.

I'd access this memory as an array - and I calculate the offset into the one-dimensional array by recogising the stride is the equivalent of one Y pixel, and so multiplying the Stride by the Y.  However, you would fall into the same trap I have so many times at this point!

```
int stride = bData.Stride / 4;  // the width is expressed in bytes, yet we need it as UInt32's.  As there's 4 bytes per UInt32, this makes sense of the divide by 4.
```

So reading pixels could be done in this way :

```
int x = 123;
int y = 321;
UInt32 pixelColour = scan0[(y * stride) + x];
```

Lastly then, don't forget to unlock your bitmaps when you're done.  An easy one to forget.
Also, if you're looking to save the changed pixels to another bitmap, you'll want to write the pixels in the same way.  I think my example using a pointer as an array to read a pixel should be obvious how to do the same to write pixels then.

One other thought - I hope you're not trying to compare Jpeg or other lossy compressed images - as the changes could be very unpredictable, and not quite what you think.  Instead, you need to use loss-less image formats such as BMP and PNG.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This didn't work for me, when I compared the UInt32 from 1 bitmap to the other, they don't match.  I'm getting a value like 252 vs 227 where as bitmap.GetPixel(x,y) on the same X/Y cords does match these two images.  I notice not a single UInt32 is ever above 256, how does this represent a formerly 32bit RGB value which was composed of 256^3 combinations?

Comment: I also tried using an UInt32 instead of the byte, not divide by 4, and that didn't match either (and gave me an exception during runtime).  I know these pixels do match but your code as it's written does not gave a positive match between two different bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

you can take a look at this class : it is an open source code that provide fast methods based on pointers to compare pixels, I could'nt find the link, so I post you the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace SampleGrabberNET
{
    public unsafe class UnsafeBitmap
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;

  // three elements used for MakeGreyUnsafe
  int width;
  BitmapData bitmapData = null;
    Byte* pBase = null;

  public UnsafeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
  {
     this.bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
  }

        public UnsafeBitmap(int width, int height)
    {
        this.bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        }

  public void Dispose()
  {
     bitmap.Dispose();
  }

  public Bitmap Bitmap
  {
 get
     {
    return(bitmap);
     }
  }

  private Point PixelSize
  {
     get
     {
    GraphicsUnit unit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    RectangleF bounds = bitmap.GetBounds(ref unit);

    return new Point((int) bounds.Width, (int) bounds.Height);
     }
  }

  public void LockBitmap()
  {
     GraphicsUnit unit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
     RectangleF boundsF = bitmap.GetBounds(ref unit);
     Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle((int) boundsF.X,
    (int) boundsF.Y,
    (int) boundsF.Width,
    (int) boundsF.Height);

     // Figure out the number of bytes in a row
     // This is rounded up to be a multiple of 4
     // bytes, since a scan line in an image must always be a multiple of 4 bytes
     // in length.
     width = (int) boundsF.Width * sizeof(PixelData);
if (width % 4 != 0)
     {
    width = 4 * (width / 4 + 1);
 }
     bitmapData =
    bitmap.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

     pBase = (Byte*) bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();
  }

  public PixelData GetPixel(int x, int y)
  {
            PixelData returnValue = *PixelAt(x, y);
     return returnValue;
  }

        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, PixelData colour)
        {
            PixelData* pixel = PixelAt(x, y);
            *pixel = colour;
        }

  public void UnlockBitmap()
  {
     bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
     bitmapData = null;
     pBase = null;
  }
        public PixelData* PixelAt(int x, int y)
        {
            return (PixelData*)(pBase + y * width + x * sizeof(PixelData));
        }
    }
    public struct PixelData
    {
        public byte blue;
        public byte green;
        public byte red;
    }
```

}

Comment: Posting someone elses code (which isn't just a snippet but a complete class this time) and saying that it's open source but nothing about which license it is under is a bit hazardous. What if it is licensed under GPL or some other that might be incompatible with his project?

Comment: it is free of use, now I do not know of what nature is his project, guess that he have to do more research

Comment: Code released under GPL is also free to use, as long as you release the rest of your project under GPL. Other licenses may also make the code free to use as long as you tell the world that you are using code by someone else so knowing the license for a larger code snippet can be very important.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren The code posted here is not for commercial use, anyway. In addition, you only know that it is "someone else's code" because the poster said so. He does not remember the owner's name but he has already acknowledged his work. He could had said nothing and you wouldn't make him sorry for trying to help. Last, but not least, this "complete class" is just a basic port of a C++ pixel manipulation. Not an original idea or anything.