# C# Comparing two images

Tags: c#, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having an image with 500 * 500 px. When I upload this image to my site it changes to 250 * 200 px. Here, I need to verify the image displayed in my site matches with the image which I chose to upload, using Selenium Web driver. Probably both of the images are same.

But since the pixels differs, can I able to match both of the images using Selenium Web driver?

I have tried Byte array conversion, GetHashCode() for comparing the images. But both Byte Array and Hash Code differs for both images.

Is this possible to compare and match these two images? Will the byte array and hash code for these images differs if their size differs even though the same image is uploaded to the site?

Kindly get me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to show us the code that handles the image upload on the server.

Comment: You should check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662354/c-sharp-faster-way-to-compare-pixels-between-two-images-and-only-write-out-the-d

Comment: You'll need to have a static copy of that resized image, compute a hash of both the original and the resized static images, download the one from the server after upload, compute a hash of that, compare it to the hash of the static file you already have...are they the same? Yay or nay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte arrays are same for both images. I have done a minor mistake by changing the resolution of the image manually and verified the byte array. So probably the byte array will be changed.

Now I have downloaded the image byte array using following code:

```
    var src = element.GetAttribute("src");

    //downloads the byte array of the image from its src
    var file = webClient.DownloadData(src);
```

Now I got the byte array of the image in the site page. I could compare this byte array with the physical image which I have selected to upload.

Thanks all for your comments.